# How do you override delegated method implementation?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

In Delphi 2007, I am using one class to implement one of the  supported interfaces of second class. This is working. The Delphi help states:

> By default, using the implements keyword delegates all interface
>   methods. However, you can use methods resolution clauses or declare
>   methods in your class that implement some of the interface methods to
>   override this default behavior.

However, when I declare a method in my second class that has the matching signature of one of the interface methods, it isn't getting called.

I wonder if this is because I'm accessing the class through another interface when I create it.

Below is a test program that demonstrates my problem:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IInterface1 = interface
  ['{15400E71-A39B-4503-BE58-B6D19409CF90}']
    procedure AProc;
  end;

  IInterface2 = interface
  ['{1E41CDBF-3C80-4E3E-8F27-CB18718E8FA3}']
  end;

  TDelegate = class(TObject)
  protected
    procedure AProc;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface1, IInterface2)
  strict private
    FDelegate: TDelegate;
    property Delegate: TDelegate read FDelegate implements IInterface1;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AProc;
  end;

procedure TDelegate.AProc;

begin
  writeln('TClassDelegate.AProc');
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDelegate := TDelegate.Create;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FDelegate.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.AProc;

begin
  writeln('TMyClass.AProc');
end;

var
  MyObj : IInterface2;

begin
    MyObj := TMyClass.Create;
   (MyObj as IInterface1).AProc;
end.
```

When I run this I get as output:

TClassDelegate.AProc

What I want is:

TMyClass.AProc

Any help appreciated.

Comment: comment out "FDelegate := TDelegate.Create;" and run it, you'll have a blast (:

Comment: @DorinDuminica, thanks for the suggestion. This didn't change the behaviour. Also in my real code, there are other properties and methods in TDelegate, so I think I need to construct an instance to avoid an access violation. Cheers.

Comment: I know, I find it odd that the code works without creating an instance, that was my only point, sorry for not being useful ):

Comment: you are calling  `IInterface1.AProc` (`myObj as IInterface1` = `TDelegate` instance) so `(myObj as IInterface1).AProc` equals `FDelegate.AProc`. so this behaviour is expected and correct. if you want to call `TMyClass.AProc`, you should call it with `TMyClass` reference. How do you want call procedure of `TMyClass`, if you have no class reference?

Comment: ok :) I've understood what you meant :) see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems you have to redeclare your method in this way:

```
TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface1, IInterface2)
strict private
  ....
  procedure test();
public
  ....
  procedure  IInterface1.AProc = test;
end;

procedure TMyClass.test;
begin
  writeln('TMyClass.AProc');
end;
```

so `IInterface1.AProc` for `TMyClass` is mapped to `Test()` (not to `FDelegate.AProc`)
and result is `TMyClass.AProc`

Comment: Thanks teran, that works for me. Note that it doesn't compile if test() is strict private, I had to make it protected.

Comment: may be :) in d2010 it compiles ok

Comment: It guess it serves me right for still using D2007. I'm just scared of porting this project. I should bite the bullet one day.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Delegating_to_a_Class-Type_Property_.28Win32_only.29) explicitly states that the behaviour you see is as designed:

> If the delegate property is of a class type, that class and its ancestors are searched for methods implementing the specified interface before the enclosing class and its ancestors are searched.

I guess in the full example you have an interface with multiple methods and are wanting the majority specified by the delegate, and specific ones overridden by the implementing class. I can't see how to achieve that with just one class, but it can be done if you introduce a second class:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IInterface1 = interface
  ['{15400E71-A39B-4503-BE58-B6D19409CF90}']
    procedure AProc;
    procedure AnotherProc;
  end;

  TDelegate = class
  protected
    procedure AProc;
    procedure AnotherProc;
  end;

  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface1)
  strict private
    FDelegate: TDelegate;
    property Delegate: TDelegate read FDelegate implements IInterface1;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AProc;
  end;

  TMyOtherClass = class(TMyClass, IInterface1)
    procedure IInterface1.AProc = AProc;
  end;

procedure TDelegate.AProc;
begin
  writeln('TDelegate.AProc');
end;

procedure TDelegate.AnotherProc;
begin
  writeln('TDelegate.AnotherProc');
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDelegate := TDelegate.Create;
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FDelegate.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.AProc;
begin
  writeln('TMyClass.AProc');
end;

var
  MyObj: IInterface1;

begin
  MyObj := TMyOtherClass.Create;
  MyObj.AProc;
  MyObj.AnotherProc;
  Readln;
end.
```

As @teran points out, if you are prepared to rename your method then there is an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks David, I had read that bit in the documentation, then lost it again in my struggles. I can see no problem with using a different name for the method in the enclosing class, so I'll go with @teran's solution.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the visibility of the property. Every time I use `implements` the properties are `protected` or `public`, same for all the examples I could find in the VCL (eg `TAutoObjectEvent`.

**Attempt #2:**

What happens if you remove the `AProc()` method from `TMyClass`? Does it then use the one on `TDelegate`?

Comment: I tried changing TMyClass.Delegate to public, but it made no difference. Similarly, changing TDelegate.AProc to public made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Attempt #2: Yes it does. That all works as expected, my problem is in trying to override the delegated implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The part of documentation you mentioned seems to be outdated. If you try to use method resolution for an interface which is used in an `implements` clause you will get compiler error [E2264: Cannot have method resolutions for interface '%s'](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_implements_intf_resolution_xml.html).

The solution shown in the link above - to simply give the procedure the same name as declared in the interface - doesn't seem to work, either, in Delphi XE (it compiles but the procedure is not called).

Comment: Thanks. It's strange that the solution in that link, unless I misread it, is the same approach that I'm trying and isn't working. Thanks for confirming that it doesn't work in XE either. I wondered if it was a peculiarity of D2007. If I ever get the time to port to XE at least I wont have to chase this foible. @teran's solution with a method resolution clause compiles and works.